# Cant pass class method to an onClick from within its render method in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sorry if this sounds like a newbish question. Haven't managed to find an answer yet.

I am basically trying to use use a class's method as a callback to the onClick in my JSX.

Here is the code of my App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.deletePost = this.deletePost.bind(this);
  }

  deletePost() {
    //   this.props.posts = this.props.posts.splice(i,1)
    console.log("Deleted the post");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to learn React</h1>
        </header>

        <div>
            <input type="text"/>
            <button>Post</button>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <div className="post-list">
            <hr/>
            {this.props.posts.map(function(post, i){
               return <div>
                    {post} - {i}
                    <button onClick={this.deletePost}>Del</button>
                    <hr/>
                </div>;
            })}
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array
};

export default App;
```

**The error I get is as follows:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'deletePost' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/components/App.js:34
  31 | {this.props.posts.map(function(post, i){
  32 |    return <div>
  33 |         {post} - {i}
> 34 |         <button onClick={this.deletePost}>Del</button>
  35 |         <hr/>
  36 |     </div>;
  37 | })}
```

So my question is how do I get pass in the deletePost function to the onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `this` is undefined inside you map function callback. Can you use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)? Do you have necessary transpilation? If yes, using an arrow function will solve that:

```
{this.props.posts.map((post, i) => { // <-- arrow function
    return <div>
        {post} - {i}
        <button onClick={this.deletePost}>Del</button>
        <hr/>
    </div>;
})}
```

If you can't or don't want to use arrow function in there, you can do something like that:

```
render() {
const deletePost = this.deletePost; // Save variable while we have access to this
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to learn React</h1>
    </header>

    <div>
        <input type="text"/>
        <button>Post</button>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div className="post-list">
        <hr/>
        {this.props.posts.map(function(post, i){
           return <div>
                {post} - {i}
                <button onClick={deletePost}>Del</button>
                <hr/>
            </div>;
        })}
    </div>

  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Or one may use `.bind(this)` on the anonymous function passed to `map`: `this.props.posts.map(function (...) {...}.bind(this))`.

Comment: Both the answer and this comment above helped. Thanks a bunch @Gleb Kost and ArneHugo

Answer (score 1):

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'deletePost' of undefined?**

Its issue with `this` binding.Use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to come over the issue.

```
 {this.props.posts.map((post, i)=>{
                   return <div>
                        {post} - {i}
                        <button onClick={this.deletePost}>Del</button>
                        <hr/>
                    </div>;
                })}
```

Answer (score 0):

For intended value of `this`, use ES6 arrow function:

```
{this.props.posts.map((post, i) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {post} - {i}
      <button onClick={this.deletePost}>Del</button>
      <hr/>
    </div>
   );
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Arrow functions (Es6 feature):

```
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
      }

      deletePost = () => {
           console.log("Deleted the post");
       }

 inside map function also use arrow

   {this.props.posts.map((post, i) => {
           return <div>
                {post} - {i}
                <button onClick={this.deletePost}>Del</button>
                <hr/>
            </div>;
        })}
```

Must be change : babel presets es2015 --> es2016 and also to add stage-2

```
ex:
   Webpack.js

 module: {
   loaders: [
      {
         test: /\.jsx?$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         query: {
            presets: ['es2016', 'react', 'stage-2'] //Add ES6 features 
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: this will still throw the same error

Comment: check webpack configuration

Comment: ok, with the last edit to the map callback, it will work